# Proving that the Laplace Transform is an isomorphism with convolution

Tags: laplace-transform, linear-transformations, convolution

My question is primarily more about the convolution integral/theorem than the proof in question, but I wanted to give some idea of why I'm asking.

The Laplace transform of the convolution $$(f\star g)(t)=\int^t_0 f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau$$

produces the product of the Laplace Transform of $f$ and $g$, that is $\mathcal L \left[(f\star g)(t)\right]=F(s)G(s)$.

My question is -- is $(f\star g)(t)$ somehow equivalent to $(f\cdot g)(t)$? I heard this method is useful for proving that the transform is a homomorphism (specifically when proving that the transform of the product is the product of the transforms).

Comment: What do you mean by "somehow equivalent"? They are obviously not the same thing, but there is an *algebra homomorphism* from $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with convolution as the product to the subalgebra of rapidly decreasing continuous functions with multiplication as the product.

Comment: Note carefully that "the transform of the product is the product of the transforms" is only an informal slogan, not a precise idea. In particular, the first occurrence of "the product" refers to convolution, whereas the second occurrence of "the product" refers to pointwise multiplication. (There is also a result that goes in the opposite direction, transforming the pointwise product into the convolution product. This is one instance of duality in Fourier analysis.)

Comment: For having a good homomorphism you know that the units should be mapped to units. The unit that is mapped to 1 (the constant function is, as you may now, $\delta$. But this is a distribution, not a function...As @symplectomorphic implicitly says, you have to turn to Fourier transform for neater results. But it will remain that Laplace transform has a tricky side. Even $\delta$ has to be "redefined" to be "causal"...